# JavaScript: Push into an Array inside an Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

**Questions:**

1. How can I push an Array into another Array located inside an Object?

**Example Coding:**

```
var myObj = {

    arrayOne: [],

    arrayTwo: []

};

var arrayLetters = ['A', 'B'];

/************************************ 

obj[arrayOne].push(arrayLetters); 

RESULT

    { 

    arrayOne: [['A', 'B']], 

    arrayTwo: [] 

    };

************************************/
```

**Comments:**

Essentially, I would like to have an key index for my various arrays.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
obj.arrayOne.push(arrayLetters);
```

or

```
obj['arrayOne'].push(arrayLetters);
```