# trouble pushing array into object (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Using Javascript, I want to push some values into an array, then push that array into an object, but I'm getting the error message `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`.

I looked at [JavaScript: Push into an Array inside an Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317253/javascript-push-into-an-array-inside-an-object) and I appear to be using the same syntax. What am I doing wrong?

```
//global vars
var arrPlayer = [];
var objPicked;

$(document).ready(function() {
   arrPlayer = [{'PlayerID':3}, {'Num': '--'}, {'First': 'John'}, {'Last': 'Smith' }, {'Position': 'QB'}];

   objPicked.push(arrPlayer); //throws error

});
```

Comment: The `objPicked` variable is uninitialized nor is it an array.

Comment: Initialize your object like this `let objPicked = {};` then if you want to add it to the object you need to assign your object a key name kinda like `objPicked.players = arrPlayer`

Comment: You are trying to push a value to an object, which is undefined. You need to have your object setup properly, for example `var objPicked = { players: [] }` and then `objPicked.players.push(arrPlayer);`.

Comment: @PatrykWojtasik Can you enter that as an answer?

Comment: @LauraNMS But his suggestion is wrong unless you want a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @LauraNMS What do you exactly mean by "pushing array into an object"?

Comment: @technophyle I do want a 2-dimensional array (I want the object to contain multiple arrays).

Comment: @LauraNMS Ok, updated my answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that you're doing wrong.

First, you cannot "push into" an empty object. Object needs to be initialized or otherwise, it would be `undefined`. So, initialize your object first:

```
var objPicked = {};
```

Now, [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a method of `Array` so even if you initialized it, there won't be a `push` method.

If I understood correctly, what you're trying to do is add an array to the object as a member and push into that array. So, you need to add it when initializing:

```
var objPicked = {
  players: []
};
```

Now, you can indeed push into `objPicked.players` because it's an array:

```
const player1 = {...};
const player2 = {...};

objPicked.players.push(player1);
objPicked.players.push(player2);
```

But if you want to "push" `arrPlayer`, which is already an array, into the array, you should not use `push` because if you do, it'd create a 2-dimensional array, so instead, you need to use [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), or simply an assignment if the original array is empty:

```
// option 1
objPicked.players = objPicked.players.concat(arrPlayer);

// option 2
objPicked.players = arrPlayer;
```

If you *do* need to push arrays into your array inside the object, you can:

```js
const objPicked = {
  players: [],
};

const arrPlayer1 = [{'PlayerID':3}, {'Num': '--'}, {'First': 'John'}, {'Last': 'Smith' }, {'Position': 'QB'}];
const arrPlayer2 = [{'PlayerID':4}, {'Num': '--'}, {'First': 'Jane'}, {'Last': 'Doe' }, {'Position': 'FW'}];

objPicked.players.push(arrPlayer1);
objPicked.players.push(arrPlayer2);

console.log(objPicked.players);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `objPicked` is undefined.

Additionally, object must contain a key value pair. So here, I've created a "data" key and assigned the `arrPlayer` list to it's value in the `objPicked` object.

```js
var arrPlayer = [];
var objPicked = {}; // define variable

arrPlayer = [{ 'PlayerID': 3 }, { 'Num': '--' }, { 'First': 'John' }, { 'Last': 'Smith' }, { 'Position': 'QB' }];

objPicked.playerData = arrPlayer; // Assign arrPlayer to objPicked as a property
console.log(objPicked);
```